# Electron/Node.js with ZeroMQ: How to keep a constant duplex communication with an external process

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipc, zeromq

I'm new to JavaScript/Node.js/Electron stack. I'm writing an Electron frontend to a C++ backend (a standalone executable), with ZeroMQ as the IPC vehicle in-between.

With languages capable of threading, I'd create a thread for polling multiple ZMQ sockets, but it seems that threading is not a thing for JS client code. Should I resort to child processes instead? But while there are already `main` and `renderer`, having yet another **PROCESS** just for **IPC** seems a little crazy to me.

What would be the canonical way to achieve what I do?

Comment: Are you using [`zeromq.js`](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js) binding? If so, take a look at the [threaded-worker](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/tree/ba91c41528cc947b8dc80cf064a176c79c6250ca/examples/threaded-worker) example